# How to extract cell state of LSTM model through model.fit()?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

My LSTM model is like this, and I would like to get state_c

```
def _get_model(input_shape, latent_dim, num_classes):

  inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
  lstm_lyr,state_h,state_c = LSTM(latent_dim,dropout=0.1,return_state = True)(inputs)
  fc_lyr = Dense(num_classes)(lstm_lyr)
  soft_lyr = Activation('relu')(fc_lyr)
  model = Model(inputs, [soft_lyr,state_c])
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
model =_get_model((n_steps_in, n_features),latent_dim ,n_steps_out)
history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

But I canot extract the `state_c` from the history. How to return that?

Comment: What do you mean by `how to get state_c?`. Your LSTM layer is already returning state_c. Could you clarify?

Comment: From which variable?

Comment: `lstm_lyr,state_h,state_c = LSTM(latent_dim,dropout=0.1,return_state = True)(inputs)` Return state is set to true, and it creates 3 tensors, last one of which is the state_c

Comment: Let me clarify, what are you trying to achieve with this model?

Comment: I would like to obatin the `state_c` 's valule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of what you mean by "How to get state_c", because your LSTM layer is already returning the `state_c` with the flag `return_state=True`. I assume you are trying to train the multi-output model in this case. Currently, you only have a single output but your model is compiled with multiple outputs.

Here is how you work with multi-output models.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

def _get_model(input_shape, latent_dim, num_classes):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    lstm_lyr,state_h,state_c = layers.LSTM(latent_dim,dropout=0.1,return_state = True)(inputs)
    fc_lyr = layers.Dense(num_classes)(lstm_lyr)
    soft_lyr = layers.Activation('relu')(fc_lyr)
    model = Model(inputs, [soft_lyr,state_c])   #<------- One input, 2 outputs
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    return model


#Dummy data
X = np.random.random((100,15,5))
y1 = np.random.random((100,4))
y2 = np.random.random((100,7))

model =_get_model((15, 5), 7 , 4)
model.fit(X, [y1,y2], epochs=4) #<--------- #One input, 2 outputs
```

```
Epoch 1/4
4/4 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6978 - activation_9_loss: 0.2388 - lstm_9_loss: 0.4591
Epoch 2/4
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6615 - activation_9_loss: 0.2367 - lstm_9_loss: 0.4248
Epoch 3/4
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.6349 - activation_9_loss: 0.2392 - lstm_9_loss: 0.3957
Epoch 4/4
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6053 - activation_9_loss: 0.2392 - lstm_9_loss: 0.3661
```

Comment: after training, which variable is the final cell state?

Comment: I don't understand, in training, you will HAVE TO PROVIDE actual data for y1 and y2. Training is not prediction. your second output currently holds `state_c` ... `model = Model(inputs, [soft_lyr,state_c])`

Comment: so you mean I have input ``state_c`` in ``model.fit()``?

Comment: The input and output of the model is what you are training it to predict. In your case, you are designing a network that predicts a class and it’s final cell state given the input. That’s how you have defined it. What are you trying to achieve. Can you describe that for me?

Comment: Just the overall problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: what is `activation_9_loss` and  `lstm_9_loss`? why there is `activation_9` and `lstm_9`?

Comment: But thank you all the same, you inspired me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. anytime