# Why are there 3 losses BUT 2 accuracies in Keras LSTM training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

My model is like this:

```
def _get_model(input_shape, latent_dim, num_classes):

  inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
  lstm_lyr,state_h,state_c = LSTM(latent_dim,dropout=0.1,return_state = True)(inputs)
  fc_lyr = Dense(num_classes)(lstm_lyr)
  soft_lyr = Activation('relu')(fc_lyr)
  model = Model(inputs, [soft_lyr,state_c])
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
model =_get_model((n_steps_in, n_features),latent_dim ,n_steps_out)
history = model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

during training I get:

```
Epoch 1/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 698ms/step - loss: 0.2338 - activation_26_loss: 0.1153 - lstm_151_loss: 0.1185 - activation_26_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - lstm_151_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2341 - val_activation_26_loss: 0.1160 - val_lstm_151_loss: 0.1181 - val_activation_26_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_lstm_151_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 34ms/step - loss: 0.2328 - activation_26_loss: 0.1153 - lstm_151_loss: 0.1175 - activation_26_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - lstm_151_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2329 - val_activation_26_loss: 0.1160 - val_lstm_151_loss: 0.1169 - val_activation_26_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_lstm_151_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/2000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 38ms/step - loss: 0.2316 - activation_26_loss: 0.1153 - lstm_151_loss: 0.1163 - activation_26_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - lstm_151_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 0.2315 - val_activation_26_loss: 0.1160 - val_lstm_151_loss: 0.1155 - val_activation_26_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_lstm_151_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

when i see history:

```
 print (history.history.keys)
    dict_keys(['loss', 'activation_26_loss', 'lstm_151_loss', 'activation_26_accuracy', 'lstm_151_accuracy', 'val_loss', 'val_activation_26_loss', 'val_lstm_151_loss', 'val_activation_26_accuracy', 'val_lstm_151_accuracy'])
```

1. which ones are the training loss and training accuracy?
2. Since there are only 2 outputs, why are there  3 losses,`loss`,`activation_26_loss`and `lstm_151_loss` BUT 2 accuracies:`activation_26_accuracy` and `lstm_151_accuracy`? what is each loss and each accuracy standing for?

Comment: Your model has two outputs, so there is a loss and metrics for each output, the names you asked are the names of the outputs (same name as the layer that produced each output).

Comment: thx. Since there are only 2  outputs, why there are 3 three losses ?

Comment: Since you are trying to solve this since your last few questions I have tried answering this in as much detail as possible. Hope this clarifies your question as well as the underlying task you are trying to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR;

1. Three losses (2+1), two losses for individual outputs, and one as the combination of the 2 losses weighed by 0.5 each. You can set both the losses explicitly and their weights as well.
2. Two accuracies since there are 2 outputs. `metrics` are just for the user to view and don't affect the neural network.

---

## Detailed explanation;

Let's try to see what you are doing here first. (I am referring to the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654159/how-to-extract-cell-state-of-lstm-model-through-model-fit) you asked to get the shapes for inputs.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

def _get_model(input_shape, latent_dim, num_classes):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    lstm_lyr,state_h,state_c = layers.LSTM(latent_dim,dropout=0.1,return_state = True)(inputs)
    fc_lyr = layers.Dense(num_classes)(lstm_lyr)
    soft_lyr = layers.Activation('relu')(fc_lyr)
    model = Model(inputs, [soft_lyr,state_c])   #<------- One input, 2 outputs
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    return model


#Dummy data
X = np.random.random((100,15,5))
y1 = np.random.random((100,4))
y2 = np.random.random((100,7))

model =_get_model((15, 5), 7 , 4)
```

---

> You are building a **supervised** model that takes an input of (15,5) shape and outputs 2 things: first a (7,) which should contain the cell_states from the 7 LSTM cells and second a (4,) vector that should contain probability values for the 4 classes. The loss you are using to train the model for learning how to predict both of the outputs is `mse`.

Since this is a supervised model, you will have to provide the model samples of inputs and outputs. If you have 100 samples then your inputs would be (100,15,5) shaped and your outputs will be (100,7) and (100,4), since you have 2 outputs.

`Loss(y_actual, y_pred)` is a function that tells the neural network how far is its prediction from the actual value. Based on this, it tells the neural network to update itself (its weights specifically using backpropagation) so that its predictions become closer and closer to actual and thus reduce the Loss.

**If the above points are clear then let's look at what this network is doing specifically**

Your current model has one input and 2 outputs.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image]

- Since you have defined `mse` as loss, both the outputs are trying to minimize `mse`. These are the 2 losses out of the 3: `activation_26_loss` which is the loss for the final `Dense` layer and `lstm_151_loss` which is the loss from the `LSTM cell state`. Keras just gives random names to these layers with numbers unless specified properly.
- The `loss` mentioned is basically the weighted average of the other 2 losses. **Ill talk about this more later.**
- The `metrics=['accuracy']` is just a metric for users to track. Since there are 2 outputs, you get 2 different accuracy metrics, one for each output. They don't affect the neural network's training.

---

Now, when working with neural networks, it's important to know which loss to use where. Here is a table describing what loss and activation functions to use for which type of network.

[image]

As you can see, it's a good practice to use `softmax` and `categorical_crossentropy` for multi-class problems. So let's try to recreate the model with this change. We want each output to have a different loss to minimize.

Also, let's say the first output is more important than the second. We can also tell the model how to weigh the losses so that it prioritizes which loss to focus on more and by how much.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

def _get_model(input_shape, latent_dim, num_classes):
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    lstm_lyr,state_h,state_c = layers.LSTM(latent_dim,dropout=0.1,return_state = True)(inputs)
    fc_lyr = layers.Dense(num_classes)(lstm_lyr)
    soft_lyr = layers.Activation('softmax')(fc_lyr)
    model = Model(inputs, [soft_lyr,state_c])             #<--- Softmax for first outputs activation
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',                      
                  loss=['categorial_crossentropy','mse'], #<--- 2 losses, one for each output
                  loss_weights=[0.4, 0.6])                #<--- 2 loss weights for final loss
    return model

#Dummy data
X = np.random.random((100,15,5))
y1 = np.random.random((100,4))
y2 = np.random.random((100,7))

model =_get_model((15, 5), 7 , 4)
utils.plot_model(model, show_layer_names=False, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Here, the final `loss` (named simply as loss) is the combination of the 2 separate losses after combining them with 0.4 and 0.6 weights.

Hope this clarifies what you are trying to achieve.

> **ONE A SIDE NOTE:** I am curious as to how you are getting the actual values for the final cell state to train the model to predict a cell state. Do let me know if that is what your intention is. It's not very clear what your final goal here is (as I had asked your previous question as well).

Comment: Thx for the detailed excellent explanation!  As far as the accuracy is concerned, how the accuracy is calculated for the two outputs?  and yes, I would like to  predict a value using using  the cell state from a well-trained LSTM model. Now I am considering whether it is a regression or classification problem.

Comment: Welcome, you can find the details around accuracy [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics). Since you have a multi output problem, it can be hybrid. The question i have is, do you have cell states with you already that you can use to train on? Or you want to train an LSTM and then fetch cell states from it. Those are 2 different things. In any case, if your question `Why are there 3 losses BUT 2 accuracies in Keras LSTM training?` is solved by this answer, do feel free to mark it as complete. Any follow up doubts you can always post a new question :)

Comment: no. i have not yet got any states. but i want to extract the hidden state from the final step. Do you have Zoom. Maybe we can talk online.

Comment: I see, let me suggest something then. You `don't` want to train on 2 outputs. what you want is to train an LSTM on the multi-class output only and then pick up the layers from the trained model UP TO the LSTM layer, pass the input the training data, and get the outputs of the LSTM (which include the hidden state).

Comment: I would recommend you do this - Try to see if you are able to solve this on your own. If facing issues open a new question specifically for this approach. I will answer that as soon as I can. Do make sure that you link the new question in this chat so I get a notification and answer it quickly.

Comment: Also, regarding zoom. I try to avoid it sorry. Let's connect via SO chat itself or if required lets connect on linkedin, details on my profile.